# Odoo 12 Error with translation on email templates

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

The default Invoice: Send by email template shows error when the partner language is German and not when the partner language is English.
I can't figure out what causes this error and how to fix this as it pops up from the default flow. How to fix this language translation error for email templates?

Comment: what is the error exactly

Comment: A email template rendering error@ElegantOdoo

Comment: I too have this problem, I still need a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue.
Just click on the translate icon in the body of the template and add the correct words which needed to be translated for the English words. Open a stable enterprise version of odoo in odoo run-bot or any working functionality. Then in that, go to the templates, select the template which shows the error. Now Click edit and click the translate icon in that html field. This opens the translation window, now all you need to do is to copy the source term and value in that database and paste it in your error occurring database. This occurs due to the language mismatch of for the words in English.